# php check 2 variables if they are equal one to another and both equal to 0

Tags: php, if-statement, equals

as the tile says, i have 2 variables that must be equal one to another and both equal to 0

i tried a few things but none worked:

```
    if (($getstatuschk === $getstatuspost) && ($getstatuschk === "0") && ($getstatuspost === "0")){ echo "status is ok";}
    else {echo "not ok!"}

    if (($getstatuschk === $getstatuspost) and ($getstatuschk === "0") and ($getstatuspost === "0")){ echo "status is ok";}
    else {echo "not ok!"}
```

i hope you can help me whit this...

thanks!

Comment: Are you handling strings or numbers? `==="0"` will be true for strings

Comment: why dont u just check if($getstatuschk == '0' && $getstatuspost == '0'){} if its true that means both the var has same value..

Comment: well, i was in a hurry when i created this code, and i realized now i was comparing 2 mysql query's with a value... after correcting this problem everything works just fine! Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code should be

```
if (($getstatuschk == $getstatuspost) && ($getstatuspost == 0)){ 
   echo "status is ok";
}
else {echo "not ok!"}
```

You don't need to check if both variables are equal to zero since you already compared them and don't put zero in quotes since this makes it a string

Answer (score 4):

If they must be equal to each other and both equal to zero then apply basic boole algebra:

```
if ($getstatuschk === 0 and $getstatuspost === 0){ echo "status is ok";}
else {echo "not ok!"}
```

Remember that a triple equal (===) also checks for data type not just value, if the two variables are known to be an integer use ===, if you don't know its type just use == and then cast it to integer using (== 0), remind that empty strings are also casted to 0's when comparing with integer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using quotes around your numbers. If you are using === then the things that you are comparing must be of the same type. So something like

```
if (($getstatuschk === $getstatuspost) && ($getstatuschk === 0) && ($getstatuspost === 0)){ echo "status is ok";}
else {echo "not ok!"}
```

might be better.